# How can I attain my PMP PDUs fast and cheap?

Tags: pmi-framework

My Project Management Professional (PMP) 3 year cycle is ending soon and I am short 15 Professional Development Unit (PDUs). What is a fast and cheap way to get these units online? Can anyone recommend good courses especially ones that allow you to learn how to use software for project management and scheduling?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for off-site recommendations/references.